# facebook sharekit

Tags: objective-c, facebook, sharekit

I tried to used Sharekit to share a message from my iPhone application but the message didn't appear.

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction) facebook
{
    [SHKFacebook shareText:@"test"];
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: no body respond please i need help

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an SHKItem, and then share it. Something like this

```
 NSString* shareText = @"text";
 SHKItem* item = [SHKItem text:shareText]; // make the SHKItem
 item.title = @"Test title";

 // Make the ShareKit action sheet
 SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

 // Display the action sheet
 [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

use this if you dont want to show an actionsheet.

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image title:title];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```